# Как подключится к xmpp серверу?

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering, xmpp

Есть программа под android (что-то типо чата). Я получил с помощью Packet Capture все что она отправляет. В логах идет получение нужных параметров через api сервиса и потом подключается к серверу xmpp и дальше в логах уже протокол jabber отправки и получения сообщений. Пытаюсь повторить подключение к серверу с помощью библиотеки S22.Xmpp под c# и каждый раз ошибка. Как подключиться к серверу?

Лог из Packet Capture (получено по api):

> ..."XMPPUseSSL":"1","XMPPHost":"xmppcluster.buhphone.com","XMPPDomain":"buhphone.com","XMPPWSURL":"/ws/","XMPPHostPort":"443","XMPPWebsocketURL":"/ws/","XMPPWebsocketPort":"80","XMPPBOSHURL":"/poll/","XMPPAlternateHosts":[]...

C#:

```
using (XmppClient client = new XmppClient("xmppcluster.buhphone.com" "aaec1528-0999-11e6-80e1-0025904f970d@buhphone.com" "*********", 443))
{
   client.Connect();
}
```

Comment: я бы для начала попробовал подключиться любым xmpp клиентом (psi, pidgin, qutim). И желательно сразу открыть xmpp console, чтобы наблюдать обмен. А вот в нем может быть много интересного.
А Ваша попытка подключиться похожа на попытку найти черную кошку в темной комнате, особенно, если она - кошка Шреденгера.

Comment: а что такое xmpp console и где открывать то ее?

Comment: вот тут показано, как открыть в psi http://codecontrol.blogspot.com/2007/10/invisible-mode-for-google-talk-xmpp.html

Comment: может я вообще не в ту сторону смотрю? еще лог из Packet Capture

Comment: GET /ws/ HTTP/1.1
Host: xmppcluster.buhphone.com
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: file://
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Lenovo A3500-FL Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Crosswalk/18.48.477.13 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-ru
Sec-WebSocket-Key: **********
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: xmpp